# Cutting excess text from files

Tags: bash, cron

I'm just wondering if there is a way to cut certain excess text from a log file when it's created? I have this as a cronjob to execute daily.

Like I want to cut a certain sentence that's added to a log file created by another process. My example here is using the `XDG-OPEN` command when it opens a new browser to go to a site or when it opens a file it creates extra information that isn't really necessary like so when I go to have it open a website it says;

```
Created new window in existing browser session.
```

and I have my script to write out a log file saying what it opened with the date, all I wish to do is truncate that extra piece of information so the result of it only writing;

```
Opened [site] on    +++ [ date ] +++
```

instead of writing;

```
Opened [site] on    +++ [ date ] +++
Created new window in existing browser session.
```

my script more or less is like this;

```
#!/bin/sh

LOG=/var/log/site_opened.log

echo -e "Opened <site_name> on    +++ [ $(date +'%a, %e %b %T %p') ] +++" >> $LOG
su - <user> xdg-open <site_url_here> >> $LOG
```

I did read the manpage for `XDG-OPEN` but there doesn't seem to be a way to suppress that message. I wasn't too sure how to go about truncating that message output after it's been written to the logfile.

also another weird thing I noticed with the log output is that at the beginning of the logfile it outputs like this;

```
-e Opened [site] on    +++ [ date ] +++
```

not sure why it's adding that `-e` option from `echo` in there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running the script under `/bin/sh`.  The `-e` option to `echo` is only supported by some shells.  Evidently, your `/bin/sh` is not one of them.  Since you don't seem to be using any feature requiring `-e`, just remove it.

```
echo "Opened <site_name> on    +++ [ $(date +'%a, %e %b %T %p') ] +++" >> $LOG
```

To suppress the unwanted message from xdg-open:

```
su - <user> xdg-open <site_url_here> | grep -v "Created new window in existing" >> $LOG
```

#### About `grep`

`grep` takes input and, line by line, compares against a pattern.  As an example, let us suppose that we have a file:

```
$ cat file
quick
brown
fox
```

With `grep`, we can select all lines from that file that contain the word "brown":

```
$ grep 'brown' file
brown
```

Alternatively, with `grep -v`, we can select all lines from that file *except* those that have the word "brown":

```
$ grep -v 'brown' file
quick
fox
```

In addition to accepting the name of a file on the command line, `grep` can accept its input from stdin:

```
$ cat file | grep -v quick
brown
fox
```

In the case of `xdg-open`, we wanted to remove the `Created` messages, so we used  `grep -v` on that message.

Comment: ah thanks, that worked. Could you explain how `grep -v` works in suppressing the message like that?

Comment: Glad it worked.  I just added a section to the answer discussing `grep`.